# Reactjs not understanding ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm reeeally new to reactjs and I was copying a tutorial (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0). I'm currently on Windows and did the following on cmd (as per tutorial):

```
npm i -g create-react-app@1.5.2
create-react-app
```

The files/directories, etc. have all been installed, but I noticed that my App.js features this syntax:

```
function App()
{
    return(...);
}
```

While the App.js from the tutorial (and many other demos) use this kind of syntax, from what I understand it's ES6:

```
class App extends Component
{
    render() 
    {
        return(...);
    }
}
```

I tried copying this syntax onto my App.js but then my react app (from typing npm start in cmd) broke. How can I fix this (i.e. use the ES6 code without breaking my project)? Does it have the exact same functionality as my above code anyway?

Here is my error message:

```
  Line 8:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   6 | class App extends Component {
   7 |   return (
>  8 |     <div className="App">
     |     ^
   9 |       <header className="App-header">
  10 |         <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
  11 |         <p>
```

I really doubt it's a parsing error, the JSX worked fine with `function App()`, but when I changed it to `class App extends Component` without touching anything else, the program broke.

Comment: possibly, you need to import `Component` from React with `import React, { Component } from "react";`? If not, can you include the error message you're getting?

Comment: My bad, I copied it wrong onto my post my but my actual code uses "extends" in lowercase and it doesn't work

Comment: @HenryWoody I added your code to the top of my App.js and I got the same "parsing error" as I had before:   Line 8:  Parsing error: Unexpected token. I strongly doubt it's a parsing error because I only altered function App() to class App extends component though. (function App() worked perfectly fine)

Comment: can you edit the question to include more about the error message, like line numbers etc. (like post the full traceback)

Comment: Sure, I just did it (I didn't mean to copy paste a whole block of unformatted code into that comment, my bad lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is from trying to return HTML/JSX from your class directly, rather than from within a function. If you're using a class, you'll need to wrap the returned HTML/JSX in the `render` function.

For example:

```js
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (...)
    }
}
```

Also, regarding the difference between the two syntax examples you posted: the first is what's called a functional component, while the second is a class-based component. In the past, class-based components were used for anything that required state (data held and manipulated internally) or life-cycle methods, while functional components were used for components that were presentation-only. With [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) (introduced , functional components can now have state and access to life-cycle methods so the two are pretty much equivalent. Put simply, you can think of a functional-component as just the `render` method of a class-based component.

In general the difference in use goes like this:

Class-based:

```js
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (...)
    }
}
```

Functional:

```js
const App = props => { // or function App(props) {
    return (...)
}
```

Check out these docs for a bit more detail:

- Class-based components: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html
- Discussion on functional components: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: In other words, OP's problem is not react, but in not correctly implementing ES6 syntax. (`return` is not a valid token within a class, only within functions)

Comment: My bad, I didn't know that was a thing. Everything's good now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

-By assuming you are begginer in React you need to install react in your machine with this command below

`npm i -g create-react-app@1.5.2`

Then to create a new react app type command `npx create-react-app yourAppName`

And you question was does React understand ES6 and answer is big

> YES

When you successfully installed and handle your app, now it's time to see how es6 works perfectly with React

Instance:

```
      // importing react library
      import React from 'react';
      // ES6 Function
      const App = () => {
      const data = [
     {
      firstname: 'Joe'
     },
     {
      firstname: 'Claire'
     },
     {
      firstname: 'John'
     }
    ]
      return  {data.map(data => <li key={data.firstname}>{data.firstname}</li>)}

}
```

Comment: Yep, I can see that now - someone resolved my issue earlier. My problem was with how I structured my react code, not with ES6 itself at all, oops.